# Is there a good AJAX/JQuery way of validating forms that works well with Django's form models?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

Especially validating forms "live"...when the user goes on to the next field, and telling the user that his previous one was not valid.

What options are available, and what would you use in conjunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ajax Validation](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation) package by django core developer [Alex Gaynor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor) is pretty awesome and probably what you want.

The best part is that you define only the standard django forms and the validation happens even after the submit.

Comment: Does this validate the entire form? Or one by one? Or both?

Comment: One by one, on focusout event. And all of them also happen on submit at the server.